# Why does Unhandeled IOException get triggerred in stream.forEach() but not in normal for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, java-8, ioexception

Unhandeled `IOException` is trigerred in below code:

```
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);
testIds.stream().forEach(testId->{
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(testId + "_" + (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000) + ".pdf"));
            zos.write(files.get(testId));
            zos.closeEntry();
        });
```

But same is not the case in below code:

```
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());    
for (Integer testId : testIds) {
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(testId + "_" + (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000) + ".pdf"));
    zos.write(files.get(testId));
    zos.closeEntry();
}
```

Comment: Both snippets have the same issue regarding unhandled exceptions.

Comment: @Tom attaching screenshot for you.

Comment: Even the Screenshot doesn't contain the obviously important method header.

Comment: In the screenshot u can clearly see that stream.forEach snippet is giving compile time error but same is not the case with other snippet.
And yes, as I said method header throws Exception.

Comment: No, you haven't said that. Neither in the question, in one of the edits of the question or in a comment under this question.

Answer (score 2):

It is not specific to `forEach`.
Checked exceptions thrown in a lambda body [has a different behavior](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) than without lambda.

> **15.27.3. Type of a Lambda Expression**
>
> A checked exception that can be thrown in the body of the lambda
>   expression may cause a compile-time error, as specified in §11.2.3.

And you can read at this point :

> **11.2.3. Exception Checking**
>
> It is a compile-time error if a lambda body can throw some exception
>   class E when E is a checked exception class and E is not a subclass of
>   some class declared in the throws clause of the function type targeted
>   by the lambda expression.

`foreach()` takes a `Consumer` and you can see that `accept()` defined in doesn't declare any exception :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Consumer<T> {

    void accept(T t);    
    ...
}
```

In fact in your imperative style snippet, the enclosing method has a `throws IOException` or `Exception` defined such as :

```
public void doThat() throws IOException {
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());    
    for (Integer testId :
                testIds) {
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(testId + "_" + (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000) + ".pdf"));
            zos.write(files.get(testId));
            zos.closeEntry();
    }
}
```

So the compilation is fine as the checked exception is "handled" : you throw it.
The same thing doesn't work with lambda for explained reason.

As workaround, you have two ways :

- not using streams. You should consider this point as it doesn't have a lot added value in your use case
- catching the exception.

About the second point, as you cannot throw the `IOException` from the lambda body, you have to handle it with a `catch` statement.
If the exception should be propagate to the client, you could re-throw a `RuntimeException` that wraps the actual one as runtime exceptions don't have the same restriction as checked exceptions in lambda body:

```
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);
testIds.stream().forEach(testId->{
           try{
                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(testId + "_" + (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000) + ".pdf"));
                zos.write(files.get(testId));
                zos.closeEntry();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                // log the exception 
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                // or throw a custom RuntimeException class if it makes more sense
            } 
        });
```

Comment: @Lino  Thank you. I did it !

Comment: even better now :)

Answer (score 2):

That is because the signature of method from the interface used in `.forEach()` (`Consumer` to be precise) doesn't declare to throw an exception.

The signature looks like the following:

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
     void accept(T t); // <-- no throws declaration
}
```

Because of that. Java forbids to throw a checked exception.

In your second snippet you probably have a method with a throws declaration like the following:

```
 public void method() throws IOException{ // <-- throws declaration here
     ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());    
     for (Integer testId : testIds) {
         zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(testId + "_" + (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000) + ".pdf"));
         zos.write(files.get(testId));
         zos.closeEntry();
     }
}
```

which is why you don't get a similar error.

A way to go around this error is to use a try catch inside the `.forEach()` and then catch the exception but this would just bloat the lambda. I would suggest that you leave your code and just use the iterative for-each loop

Comment: JFYI I was changing the old for loop to stream.forEach() and both the snippets is in same method.
And yes method throws Exception.

Comment: Finally, almost same content as mine :)

Comment: @davidxxx yes it was kind of a race ;)

Answer (score 0):

The exception will be thrown from within the lambda meaning that the caller of the lambda needs to catch/check the exception. I assume that you have a `try-catch` or `throws` clause outside your snippet?

Since `forEach` does not check the exception for you the `IOException` is unhandled. You must handle it instead. Simplest way to do this is catching the exception and wrapping it (e.g. in a Runtime exception).

```
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);
testIds.stream().forEach(testId->{
    try{
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(testId + "_" + (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000) + ".pdf"));
        zos.write(files.get(testId));
        zos.closeEntry();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: simplest way would be to not use `Streams` for such an easy operation in the first place

Answer (score -1):

It appears you are closing the stream in the loop. The second time around, the stream is closed.

Comment: The OP appears to be getting a compile error because he is not declaring a checked exception. He said IOException...